# How to create bidirectional histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram, data-visualization

Here is some data:
dat <- cbind(letters, runif(length(letters)), rnorm(length(letters))^2)

I would like to create a bidirectional histogram. I would like letters to go down the center, and have the uniform data go left and the normal data go right. This would be similar to the bidirectional barplots you can generate in ggplot2, but I want them distinctly split with the letters going down the 'spine'. Adding color and various other directions would be a plus, but I can figure that out once I get the proper framework in place

Comment: It is not clear what you want to plot.  I suspect that you do not mean histogram but rather barchart. For the uniform data the length of the bar would be the value of the uniform data. OK. But what about the normal data. That will assume negative values so it is not clear what you want the lengths to be.

Comment: sorry. edited to fix data command. maybe a bar chart would work. essentially getting the layout correct is what i'm worried about most. labels down the middle. one set of values going one direction. another set of values going the other. if there are any packages that i haven't found yet that will do this i'm game to learn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give us much to go on, but maybe this is close to what you had in mind?

```
dat <- data.frame(
  letters, 
  unif=runif(length(letters)), 
  norm=rnorm(length(letters))^2)

par(mar=c(3, 1, 0, 1.5), cex=1, mfrow=c(1, 2))

bplt <- barplot(-dat[[2]], horiz=TRUE, xaxt="n")

axis(1, -seq(0, max(dat[[2]]), length.out=5), 
   round(seq(0, max(dat[[2]]), length.out=5), 2), cex.axis=0.8)
axis(4, bplt, dat[[1]], lty=0, las=1, cex.axis=0.8)

barplot(dat[[3]], horiz=TRUE, cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

This type of plot is well known from the field of demographics where it's often referred to as a 'pyramid plot'. I'm sure you'll find more advanced solutions if you search around.

Comment: absolutely. You're my hero. I wasn't sure how to describe it. Thank you so much!